# Incorrect output when counting the occurence of each character in a given string (beginner Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program that saves a string into an array and then gives the number of  occurences for each of the characters in that string.

This is my code so far:

```
String string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string.toLowerCase();

int[] count = new int[26];
char[] vrstica = string.toCharArray();


for(char crka : vrstica){
    int indeks = ((int)('z') - (int)('a'));
    count[indeks]++;
}
    for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
        if(count[i] != 0){
            System.out.println((char)('a'+ i) + " > " + count[i]);
        }
    }
```

and this is the output I am currently getting:

z > 43

I am using .toCharArray() because that was the tip given in the instructions for this assignment, but I am not completely sure if the way I am using it is correct.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `int indeks = (int)crka - (int)('a'));`

Comment: well, your string has 43 characters and as noted above, the code is counting each character as being a `z` || BTW `string.toLowerCase();` is not useful, its result is not being used (`String` is immutable) || BTW2 there is no need to cast a `char` to do `int` arithmetic

Comment: @OldProgrammer When I try this, I get the .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error, saying that Index -13 is out of bounds for length 26. Where did I go wrong here? Any other methos I could use to input a string into an array? Thanks :)

Comment: The first letter is `T` and `'T' - 'a'` is -13, you can't assume all characters in the string are greater than `a`

Comment: as I already wrote... `string.toLowerCase();` has no impact since its result is never used - it does **not** change the original `String` - `String`s in Java are immutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few problem with your code.

```
string.toLowerCase();
```

toLowerCase returns the lower case of string, and doesn't change the original string.  You need to capture the returned string.

```
string = string.toLowerCase();
```

You need to change `((int)('z')` to `((int)(crka)`.

You also need to handle the space character ' '.

Here's are the changes:

```
String string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string = string.toLowerCase();  // <<<  change here

int[] count = new int[26];
char[] vrstica = string.toCharArray();


for(char crka : vrstica){
    int indeks = ((int)(crka) - (int)('a'));  // <<< change here
    if (crka != ' ') count[indeks]++;  // <<< change here
}

for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
  if(count[i] != 0){
    System.out.println((char)('a'+ i) + " > " + count[i]);
  }
}
```